# Counting values while ignoring certain consecutive records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a log table for a service that periodically measures various metrics for my software. The (simplified) table is as below:

```
+-------------------+--------+-----+
|      ENTRYDATETIME|  METRIC|VALUE|
|2018-01-16 12:30:00|MyMetric|    0|
|2018-01-16 13:00:00|MyMetric|    5|
|2018-01-16 13:30:00|MyMetric|   50|
|2018-01-16 14:00:00|MyMetric|   65|
|2018-01-16 14:30:00|MyMetric|   10|
|2018-01-16 15:00:00|MyMetric|    0|
|2018-01-16 15:30:00|MyMetric|   13|
|2018-01-16 16:00:00|MyMetric|   50|
|2018-01-16 16:30:00|MyMetric|   20|
|2018-01-16 17:00:00|MyMetric|    0|
+-------------------+--------+-----+
```

I need a query that will count the number of times that the number in the value field exceeded 40, but counts consecutive times as a single event I.E. the result of the above table should be 2.

To add more context: This is measuring how many files are waiting to be processed by a service, and I want to measure how many times a backlog has appeared throughout the day. The backlog that is measured at 14:00 in the above example is the same backlog that was first observed at 13:30, so I want that record excluded from any results.

I can probably do it with a cursor just looping through the records one by one, but there will be a lot of different metrics and criteria I'll be trying this against, so if there is a better way to do this can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean when you say that you want to count consecutive times as a single event. As a single query or a single statement per line?

Comment: Which version of `Sql Server` you are using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should return your expected result

```
select
    count(distinct grp)
from (
    select
        *, rn1 - row_number() over (order by ENTRYDATETIME) grp
    from (
        select
            *, row_number() over (order by ENTRYDATETIME) rn1
        from
            MyTable
    ) t
    where
        VALUE > 40
) t
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Uzi. :)

Comment: Nice solution, have +1 mate!

Answer (score 2):

This is a gap and island problem

```
select count(*)
from 
(
    select exceed, grn
    from
    (
        select *,
               row_number() over (order by ENTRYDATETIME) -
               row_number() over (partition by exceed order by ENTRYDATETIME) grn
        from
        (
          select *, 
               case when value > 40 then 1 else 0 end exceed
          from your_table
        ) t1
    ) t2
    where exceed = 1
    group by exceed, grn
) t3
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8c82886df2093aeffa8e30f14d2a4cd6)

The magic is in the identification of consecutive sequences. That is achieved using two `row_number()` functions: the first is global and the second one is per group (exceed in my case). The difference allows you to identify the consecutive sequences.

Comment: Gap and Island problem... thanks Radim, thats a perfect description of it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is enough that the result returns 2, this is how i would do it, but i dont believe this is what you need since it is so basic and the fact that you are mentioning cursors. The GroupCTE just groups the two values having 50 together and returns two rows that you can count using the count rows function

```
WITH GroupCTE AS
(
    SELECT Metric,Value
    FROM Tablename
    WHERE VALUE > 40
        AND METRIC = 'MyMetric'
    GROUP BY METRIC,VALUE
)
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM GroupCTE
```

Comment: I updated the code as i understood more of your predicament after writing the code ;D I didnt see the two rows with 50 at first.

Comment: Hi Werner,

Deleted my comment, posted it after I saw your edit. Many thanks for your help, appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `lag` function; Check whether the value exceeded 40 and its previous value <= 40, in which case count it as one:

```
;with lag_t as(
  select 
    value,
    lag(value,1,0) over (order by ENTRYDATETIME) as l_value
  from t
) 
select
  sum(case when value > 40 and l_value <= 40 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from lag_t;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/66781/10).

Comment: Thanks Psidom, will try this out. :)